# How to full copy the C:\Windows folder?

Tags: backup, windows-server-2012, robocopy, copy, mirroring

I have a question about cmd - *robocopy*, on my server. 
Is it possible to use that command as a way to emergency backup all files from C:\Windows? I am going to do some Windows Server Updates, and I have to save system catalogue in a way like it is. 
Is it possible for the robocopy operation to copy all the files included hidden, system and small files?

Comment: Ok, it is close but that programm don't run on Windows Server. Any else?

Comment: Why my question is still on hold? 
I edited it, and make it to be 100% site standards.

Comment: About that programs, i don't want to make disk image, because all disk is 3 TB+, I need only Windows folder, and I have checked a lot of 3third party tools, but they don't work on server, or have problems to copy all files. Still need help.

Comment: Thank You, Tim, for Your response. The server partitions are like they are, I have not made it, but I have to do something to backup Windows folder, not reinstall. 
But I don't need third party tool, I have checked it (almost) all. In my question I only asking about cmd 'robocopy' and how to use it to copy Windows folder, where is my request about any other product? 
And still this question is inappropriate, I am asking why.

Comment: Rudeness? o.O I am really surprised. 
I don't understand You Tim, you have to have some problems with yourself, but it is not my case and don't join me on that. 
Again, thank you for the best advice, I'm going to get from you, but it didn't help at all :)

Answer (score 1):

Robocopy can be used to backup data, but it is a relatively poor choice to backup an operating system, as it won't backup the boot sector and partition table, so you can't use it as a disaster recovery solution.

As you have been already told, use an imaging tool or other kind of backup solution that can restore your system to a working state.

Comment: Ok, so if something happens during/after Windows Update, and later, I will paste Windows folder in state like it was before Update, you say, that it won't turn back changes, done by patches? But they are stored in Windows folder, so why it would not work? Thank You Sven for response.

Answer (score 1):

Using robocopy you will run into these problems

Assuming you backup the c:\windows folder where the system is booted from

**Backup**

- You can't backup all files, some are exclusively opened by other processes
- You can't backup them in a consistent state (especially when it is a domain controller)

**Restore**

- You can't restore the files when they are currently used by other processes
- The [windows file protection (WFP)](https://support.microsoft.com/de-de/help/222193/description-of-the-windows-file-protection-feature) will prevent changings to system files

Quote WFP:

> WFP protects critical system files that are installed as part of Windows (for example, files with a .dll, .exe, .ocx, and .sys extension and some True Type fonts)

---

=> Use any other tool, like the built in server backup.

Look: [Set up or customize server backup](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server-essentials/manage/set-up-or-customize-server-backup) by Microsoft

**Edit**

Using the built in server backup you can choose to **backup only** the `system state` (Boot files, system files, all files protected by Windows File Protection, Active Directory , Sysvol , Certificate Services ) and the `c:\windows` directory. Nevertheless, this can lead to an inconsistent system.

Comment: But there are a lot of programs which give you opportunity to copy entire C:\ volume, so, in that case, how and why they are copying files which robocopy could not? Because when you do C:\ image, there is Windows folder too, didn't it? 
And, are there a lot of files in which could be an probblem, and are they essencial to Windows to work? 
About restore, i think it will be done if something goes wrong, so then i will turn off server and copy that files out of windows layer, via rescue disk or DOS copy.

Comment: @Renver If you realize it with robocopy, mind to copy also the file permissions.

Comment: @Renver They most likely use the volume shadow copy (vss) functionality. This can be also used with robocopy, but it's awkward and error prone. Some inspirations: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/adioltean/2005/01/05/script-recipe-of-the-week-how-to-copy-an-opened-file/